# C# Sorting a Linq List<XElement> by Date node comprised of Wed, 30 Jul 2014 12:00:00 -0700

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, date

I have an XML Document. Using XDocument to load and pass into a var. Created a list using AddRange.

Trying to sort this list. Code below:

```
string url = _url.StartsWith("http") ? _url : HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_url);

var doc = XDocument.Load(url);

elements.AddRange(doc.XPathSelectElements(_xpath).ToList());

sortElement = elements.OrderBy(element => element.Element("pubDate").Value).ToList();
```

This is sorting by alpha. I need to sort by DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Is `pubDate` format `Wed, 30 Jul 2014 12:00:00 -0700`?

Comment: You could use ... `OrderBy(element => DateTime.ParseExact(element.Element("pubDate").Value, "<your specific format>").ToList();`  Where you still need to fill in the specific date time format you need.

Comment: What do you mean specific format? Just want to go from newest date to oldest.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sortElement = elements.OrderBy(element => DateTime.Parse(element.Element("pubDate").Value).ToList();
```

Comment: ``OrderByDescrnding`` for newest date